# What is the name of the background instrumental theme that starts at 2:19 in episode 28 of My Hero Academia?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

Could any of you please tell me what is the name of the background instrumental music in episode 28 (season 2 episode 14) of My Hero Academia, which starts at 2:19? I'd really appreciate it. (The situation is training of Midoriya with Gran Torino.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a slightly modified version of "Sendai no Meiyuu", track 10 of disc 2 of [TV ANIMATION MY HERO ACADEMIA 2nd ORIGINAL SOUND TRACK](https://vgmdb.net/album/69367).